# Firefox: CSS aspect ratio doesn't work in Firefox but does in Chrome

Tags: css, reactjs, firefox, sass, styled-components

I'm using `display: grid` in my app. I want the grid items to always be square, therefore, I have given them an aspect ratio of 1/1. In Chrome this works as expected, but in Firefox the aspect ratio code doesn't seem to change anything. I have commented the line out to see if this makes a difference in Firefox, it doesn't but it does in Chrome.

I'm using styled components to style the grid and the grid items . Is my problem due to lack of compatibility with Firefox on behalf of styled components or CSS? If someone could help me fix this, I'd be very grateful. I have researched into this problem but could not find anywhere that shows a fix, I think it's because CSS's aspect ratio is quite new still?

Also, the app works correctly with Safari on a mac, Microsoft Edge on a windows laptop and Google Chrome on Android.

My code...

Grid component styles

```
    export const StyledGrid = styled.div`
  width: calc(100% - 8rem);
  margin: 1rem 4rem;
  h3 {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }

  // grid things
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(14rem, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 8rem;
  grid-row-gap: 8rem;

  // Grid and font sizing media queries
  @media (min-width: 1502px) {
    h3 {
      font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 1326px) and (min-width: 1300px) {
    grid-row-gap: 6rem;
  }
  @media (max-width: 1089px) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(12.75rem, 1fr));
    grid-row-gap: 6rem;
    h3 {
      font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 749px) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(12rem, 1fr));
    grid-row-gap: 5.5rem;
    h3 {
      font-size: 1.3rem;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 624px) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
    grid-row-gap: 5rem;
  }
  @media (max-width: 494px) {
    grid-row-gap: 4rem;
  }

  @media (max-width: 410px) {
    grid-row-gap: 3.25rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(5rem, 1fr));
    h3 {
      font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 346px) {
    h3 {
      font-size: 1.1rem;
    }
  }
  @media (max-width: 331px) {
    h3 {
      font-size: 1rem;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 319px) {
    grid-row-gap: 3rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(6rem, 1fr));
  }

  // Grid column gap and margin media queries

  // Media queries
  @media (max-width: 1009px) {
    grid-column-gap: 6rem;
  }
  @media (max-width: 729px) {
    grid-column-gap: 4rem;
  }
  @media (max-width: 391px) {
    grid-column-gap: 3rem;
  }
  @media (max-width: 370px) {
    grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  }
  @media (max-width: 1299px) {
    margin: 3.25rem 4rem;
  }
  @media (max-width: 650px) {
    margin: 3.25rem 2rem;
    width: calc(100% - 4rem);
  }
  @media (max-width: 391px) {
    margin: 3.25rem 2rem 3.25rem 1.5rem;
    width: calc(100% - 3rem);
  }
  @media (max-width: 370px) {
    margin: 3.25rem 1.5rem 3.25rem 1rem;
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  }
`;
```

Grid item component styles...

```
const StyledRecord = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;

  img {
    border-radius: 1rem;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  h3 {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.63%;
    color: ${(props) => (props.theme === "light" ? "#343434" : "white")};
  }
`;
```

Comment: Is your Firefox up to date https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for the reply! My Firefox was up to date, but you saying that led me onto finding what the issue was. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Got it! All I had to do was remove the definition of height for the image and that solved my issue. Must've had something to do with the way Firefox processes the style that is different to Chrome.

```
const StyledRecord = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  h3 {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.63%;
    color: ${(props) => (props.theme === "light" ? "#343434" : "white")};
  }
`;
```